# changing Div order in a div main container, javascript DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodelist

i want to move a div form the start to the end in  a the same div:from 1-2-3 to 2-3-1

my code

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
const firstCard = document.querySelectorAll(".card")[0].innerHTML;
cards[0].remove();
document.getElementById("mainC").appendChild(firstCard);
```

```html
<div id="mainC">
 <div class="card"> 1 </div>
 <div class="card"> 2 </div>
 <div class="card"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

i want to move a div form the start to the end in  a the same div:from 1-2-3 to 2-3-1

Comment: I would highly recommend to use a CSS solution(`order` property). If you insist on a JS solution the use the `dataTransfer` API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your original code,**we need to remove `.innerHTML`**,then it will work

### ```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
const firstCard = document.querySelectorAll(".card")[0];// remove .innerHTML and it will work
cards[0].remove();
document.getElementById("mainC").appendChild(firstCard);
```

```html
<div id="mainC">
 <div class="card"> 1 </div>
 <div class="card"> 2 </div>
 <div class="card"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

Another solution is to store the content into an array and change the array element order

```js
let divs = []
document.querySelectorAll('#mainC .card').forEach(d =>{
  divs.push(d.outerHTML)
})
divs.push(divs.shift())
document.querySelector('#mainC').innerHTML = divs.join('')
```

```html
<div id="mainC">
 <div class="card"> 1 </div>
 <div class="card"> 2 </div>
 <div class="card"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have used document.querySelectorAll(".card")[0].innerHTML which gives '1' which is not type "node" so it will give an error when appending as a child.

remove .innerHTML and it will work

here is an example that removes the first child and append it to the end.

```js
      const shuffle = () => {
        const parent = document.querySelector("#mainContainer");
        const childrens = [...parent.children];
        parent.appendChild(childrens.splice(0,1)[0]);
      };
```

```html
    <button type="button" onclick=shuffle()> suffel</button>
    <div id="mainContainer">
      <div class="card">1</div>
      <div class="card">2</div>
      <div class="card">3</div>
    </div>
```